# Does there exist a a hashmap with <key, key/value, value>?

Tags: hashmap, hashtable

So if one needed to chain hashmaps together, instead of having to create another map, have the value of the first key be a key to the next value, and so on. Like an n-order hashmap might look like

```
<key, key/value_1, key/value_2, ..., value_n/>.
```

Comment: What you describe sounds like a Tree structure. You might check out the various implementations of whichever language you are looking at.

Comment: Why not just use a linked list?